# Inverting amplifier beginner question

Tags: capacitor, inverting-amplifier

there is a book that shows common circuits

[image]

The text says that C1 helps preventing any DC from reaching the transistor (I understand that) But it also says that C1 helps preventing any DC from Q1 getting back into the previous stage.

What does it mean? How?

Comment: The bias network applies a voltage to the base.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an amplifier or mixer stage before this. To work properly the output of this needs to be biased at certain dc levels. These levels may not be the same as the base bias for this stage. The capacitor allows the different DC bias levels to be connected but the AC signal to pass through.

A capacitor will block DC but allow AC to pass.

Can I suggest that instead of starting with some quite complex concepts you work through some of the basic tutorials available on the internet this https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-current-resistance-and-ohms-law and the other sparkfun tutorials are written for the absolute beginner.

Comment: I know this is a site for electrical engineers, but could you explain in a way someone who never did electronics before could understand?

Comment: No I can not. If you do not understand the operation of capacitors and the need for different DC bias levels at different places in amplifiers you will not be able to understand even the simplest answer. It is beyond the scope of this question to teach you all that. You need to put in some research effort google is your friend. Look for capacitor theory and basic amplifier design.

Comment: I understand how a capacitor works but I got no idea what bias levels are. There must be a way to answer my question in a way that someone who has little knowledge in electronics can understand because the book where my question comes from is a book for people beginning in electronics.

Comment: @gigi pointer to some beginners tutorials added to answer

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out the answer to both your questions with a single insight and without resorting to "passes AC, blocks DC" (which may or may not be intuitive to you, now.)

Imagine that there's no active signal. Just imagine that the input side of \$C_1\$ is attached to some arbitrary biasing pair of resistors, just like \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are right now. But suppose they have different values. What happens given enough time? Well, \$C_1\$ will charge up to exactly the voltage difference between the two points (as if the capacitor wasn't there.)

Now pause for a moment and think about that. \$C_1\$ will just naturally charge up to exactly the voltage difference ***as if it wasn't there***. That is, given some time of course.

In a sense here, \$C_1\$ forms a *bridge* between two DC voltage nodes. The DC voltage node we can't see in the schematic that is "to the left" of \$C_1\$ and the voltage node to the right of \$C_1\$ (which is attached to \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ and \$Q_1\$.) It just bridges the gap, given some time. That's all it does.

Now, if the *input* wiggles a little bit and does so fast enough then the other side of \$C_1\$ will wiggle the same amount on the right side, too. The voltage difference across \$C_1\$ won't change, because there won't be enough time for it to change if the signal wiggles things *fast* enough. (Which, if designed right, should always be approximately *true*.)

So the circuit will take a few hundred milliseconds to charge \$C_1\$ and then, after that startup period, \$C_1\$ is nothing more than a simple bridge between two different circuits, isolating their DC differences while allowing fast AC signalling to cross over.

Another way of seeing \$C_1\$ is that the voltage across it ***adds*** just the right amount of voltage to *move* the signal from its DC bias point left of \$C_1\$ to its DC bias point on the right side.

That works both ways, of course. The DC biasing on the right doesn't affect the DC biasing on the left because \$C_1\$ has just the right voltage difference. Neither side's DC bias point is impacted by the other side's DC bias point, as \$C_1\$ has that exact, needed voltage difference to bridge between the two different DC quiescent points.

Convenient.

Answer (score 0):

C1 is a *DC blocking cap*.  It does this in both directions.  Both your statements are therefore correct.

The DC level at the right side of C1 is carefully set by R1, R2, and to some extent R3 to keep the transistor in its "linear" region over the signal amplitude of interest.  C1 prevents the DC level of the previous circuit from messing this up.  Conversely, the average DC bias at the right side of C1 could mess up whatever is connected to its left side.  It protects both sides from each other by not providing any DC connection.